# Programa usa o módulo threading mas não observei nenhum paralelismo na execução. O que está errado?

Tags: python, python-3.x, thread, multithreading

Fiz um script para diminuir a qualidade de algumas mp3, chamando o programa ffmpeg através do módulo subprocess. Adicionei Threads pensando em fazer o processo em paralelo para vários arquivos ao mesmo tempo.
O programa funciona mas não vi NENHUM paralelismo. Fiquei acompanhando a execução do programa e observei que, aparentemente, é "convertida" uma MP3 por vez. Onde está o paralelismo? O que eu fiz de errado?

Observei também que, executando pelo IDLE, o prompt '"liberado" embora o programa continue executando, ou seja, não consigo saber quando terminou...

```
import subprocess

from threading import Thread


def ConverteMusica(a):

    input_file_fmt = '{}.mp3'
    output_file_fmt = a

    for x in range(1, 5):
        subprocess.call(['ffmpeg',
                         '-i',
                         input_file_fmt.format(x),
                         '-acodec',
                         'libmp3lame',
                         '-ac',
                         '2',
                         '-ab',
                         '16k',
                         '-ar',
                         '44100',
                         output_file_fmt.format(x)])


MeuConversor1 = Thread(target=ConverteMusica,args=["Personalidades_Famosas_Elogiam_Cultura_Vedica.mp3"])
MeuConversor2 = Thread(target=ConverteMusica,args=["Sri_Caitanya_caritamrta_Madhya_lila_20_378_Aula_100.mp3"])
MeuConversor3 = Thread(target=ConverteMusica,args=["Sri_Caitanya_caritamrta_Madhya_lila_22_1_Aula_101.mp3"])
MeuConversor4 = Thread(target=ConverteMusica,args=["Sri_Caitanya_caritamrta_Madhya_lila_22_66_Aula_102.mp3"])


MeuConversor1.start()
MeuConversor2.start()
MeuConversor3.start()
MeuConversor4.start()
```

Comment: Não é recomendável em geral usar threads no Python, porque elas na maioria dos casos não aumentam a performance do programa. Isso se deve ao [GIL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/253308/o-que-%C3%A9-global-interpreter-lock-gil). Ao invés disso, use o módulo `multiprocessing`, que funciona de modo bastante similar a threads mas contorna o problema do GIL criando vários processos de Python separados. Além disso, recomendo que use uma [Pool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool), pra que não tenha que ter uma variável pra cada processo.

Comment: Relacionada ou até duplicata porque no findo a resposta é esta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1946/101, o que conforma o comentário do Pedro. No caso de Python provavelmente o GIL torna impraticável ter algum ganho em quase todas situações.

Comment: @Maniero: É sempre mais melhor usar multiprocessing ao invés de threads, então?

Comment: Não necessariamente, mas em Python costuma ser. A vantagem da thread é compartilhar estado enquanto tem mais de uma linha de processamento, só que é preciso garantir que nunca tenha 2 linhas acessando o dado ao mesmo tempo a não ser que ambos sejam só leitura. Isto não é simples e sempre que seja feito artificialmente por um *lock* potencialmente impede o processamento paralelo, que é o que o GIL acaba fazendo. Em um processo separado não compartilha estado, então tudo vai bem. Se pode fazer isto, faça. Mas se tiver que copiar todos os dados de um processo para outro, não compensa

Comment: @Maniero: seria assim? pastebin.com/TZ4YwJ77  Aparentemente, meu programa está em looping!

Comment: Eu não tenho experiência específica fazendo isto em Python, então não posso afirmar.

Comment: @PedrovonHertwig: pastebin.com/TZ4YwJ77 Aparentemente, meu programa está em looping!