# Programa para converter mp3 utilizando o módulo multiprocessing está em looping

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

```
import subprocess

from multiprocessing import Process, Lock

def ConverteMusica(a,lock):

    input_file_fmt = '{}.mp3'
    output_file_fmt = a

    for x in range(1, 5):
        subprocess.call(['ffmpeg',
                         '-i',
                         input_file_fmt.format(x),
                         '-acodec',
                         'libmp3lame',
                         '-ac',
                         '2',
                         '-ab',
                         '16k',
                         '-ar',
                         '44100',
                         output_file_fmt.format(x)])


lock = Lock()

MeuConversor1 = Process(target=ConverteMusica,args=("Personalidades_Famosas_Elogiam_Cultura_Vedica.mp3",lock))


MeuConversor1.start()
MeuConversor1.join()
```

Tentei adaptar o programa que eu já tinha trocando o Threading por multiprocessing. Não sei porque o programa está em looping! O que está errado?

Comment: Loop? Do tipo, o programa reinicia toda vez?

Comment: @Anderson Carlos Woss: Fica travado!

Comment: Você quer executar o comando `ffmpeg` ao mesmo tempo em 4 processos distintos? É isso?

Comment: @Anderson Carlos Woss: eu gostaria de converter vários arquivos "ao mesmo tempo", de forma a não ter que esperar um acabar para começar a converter o outro!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Por hora ficarei te devendo o erro no seu código, pois precisarei analisar com mais tempo, mas uma alternativa para o problema é utilizar o módulo `asyncio`, visto que o processamento em si do seu programa é executado fora do Python, então não terá problemas com o [GIL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/253308/5878). Basicamente você só estará utilizando o Python para iniciar os processos.

Com o `asyncio`, poderia fazer algo semelhante a:

```
import asyncio

async def command(*args):
  process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(*args, stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE)
  stdout, stderr = await process.communicate()
  return stdout.decode() if process.returncode == 0 else stderr.decode()
```

Como não posso reproduzir o mesmo comando que você deseja com o `ffmpeg`, irei demonstrar um código que efetua o `ping` em múltiplos servidores. Assim:

```
URLS = [
  'woss.eng.br',
  'pt.stackoverflow.com',
  'chat.stackexchange.com',
  '127.0.0.1'
]

commands = [command('ping', '-c', '10', url) for url in URLS]
```

A lista `commands` será composta de todos os comandos que desejo executar em paralelo, ou seja, neste caso, o comando `ping` nos quatro servidores indicados. Assim, basta definir o laço de eventos do `asyncio` e aguardar as respostas:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
processes = asyncio.gather(*commands)
result = loop.run_until_complete(processes)
loop.close()

print(result)
```

O código completo, com alguns `print` a mais para acompanhar a execução, seria:

```
import asyncio, time

async def command(*args):
  process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(*args, stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE)
  print('Iniciado o processo', process.pid)
  stdout, stderr = await process.communicate()
  return stdout.decode() if process.returncode == 0 else stderr.decode()

URLS = [
  'woss.eng.br',
  'pt.stackoverflow.com',
  'chat.stackexchange.com',
  '127.0.0.1'
]

START = time.time()

commands = [command('ping', '-c', '10', url) for url in URLS]

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
processes = asyncio.gather(*commands)
result = loop.run_until_complete(processes)
loop.close()

END = time.time()

print(result)
print('Tempo', END - START)
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/NocturnalSoulfulDeclaration)</sup>

Rodando, verá que executará em aproximadamente 9 segundos, que é o tempo aproximado do comando `ping` para um domínio, transferindo 10 pacotes, mesmo que foram executados quatro comandos, diferente se os [mesmos comandos fossem executados em sequência](https://repl.it/@acwoss/FussyJoyousStartups), totalizando quase 40 segundos.