# Receber uma URL do teclado e pingá-la no Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

- Recebe uma URL digitada via teclado
- Realiza um ping da respectiva URL
- Retorna o ip (se houver) da URL digitada

Ex.: Digite uma URL: www.google.com

Pinging www.google.com [172.217.162.164] with 32 bytes of data:
 Reply from 172.217.162.164: bytes=32 time=64ms TTL=54

Reply from 172.217.162.164: bytes=32 time=56ms TTL=54

Reply from 172.217.162.164: bytes=32 time=55ms TTL=54

Reply from 172.217.162.164: bytes=32 time=57ms TTL=54

Ping statistics for 172.217.162.164:

Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),

Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:

Minimum = 55ms, Maximum = 64ms, Average = 58ms

www.google.com | 172.217.162.164

Deseja continuar? [S]im [N]ao

Agora sempre que executo o programa ele dá a resposta "up" independente do que seja digitado no campo site, com isso ocorre a seguinte mensagem:

Digite o site: www.ggghhh.com.br
www.ggghhh.com.br is up!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\cwo\Downloads\python\TRABALHO.py", line 22, in 
    ip = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed

```
import os
import subprocess
import socket

list_site = []
list_ip = []
hostname = ""
continuar = ""

while continuar != "nao":
    hostname = str(input("Digite o site: "))
    list_site.append(hostname)
    response = os.system("ping -c4 " + hostname)

    if response == 0:
        print (hostname, 'is down!')
        ip = 0
        list_ip.append(0)

    else:
        print (hostname, 'is up!')
        ip = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
        list_ip.append(ip)

    continuar = str(input("Deseja digitar mais algum site? "))

for i in range(len(list_site)):
    print(list_site[i], list_ip[i])
```

Comment: Veja se esta resposta te ajuda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/290379/5878

Comment: Não. Dei uma olhada no programa funcionando no https://repl.it/@acwoss/NocturnalSoulfulDeclaration

Comment: Se nenhuma das perguntas indicadas lhe ajudar, busque [edit] a sua descrevendo melhor o problema. Se realmente forem diferente, poderemos reabrir a pergunta sem problemas.

Comment: Ok, estou verificando as respostas.
Obrigado

Comment: Não ficou muito claro o objetivo da sua edição. Você parece apenas ter descrito de forma mais completa, porém o problema permanece o mesmo. Você conseguiu efetuar o ping? Coloque na pergunta o código que você fez.

Comment: O que pus depois não é código. É para ilustrar o que o programa deve mostrar quando executado.

Comment: Atualize a pergunta com o seu código, bem como o resultado obtido. Se deu erro, poste a mensagem de erro.

Comment: Revise as suas condições. Não entendi porque quando o [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) retorna 0 o site está *down*. Recomendo também testar com um domínio que exista ou trate as exceções que são lançadas pelas funções utilizadas quando o domínio não existir. Testei aqui e funcionou perfeitamente: https://repl.it/@acwoss/OverdueTruthfulEntropy

Comment: tem que ter a opção de digitar o site para ver se existe

Comment: Por isso eu disse que você deve rever as condições que utilizou, pois a lógica em si funciona, só não está verificando se existe ou não da maneira certa.

Comment: response == 0 não significa que o site não responde?

Comment: "*On Windows, the return value is that returned by the system shell after running command. [...] which returns the exit status of the command run.*" Ou seja, 0 significa que o comando executou sem erros.

Comment: mesmo que eu inverta a ordem e coloque
     if response == 0:
        print (hostname, 'is up!')
        ip = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
        list_ip.append(ip)
        
    else:
        print (hostname, 'is down!')
        ip = 0
        list_ip.append(ip)
    continuar = str(input("Deseja digitar mais algum site? "))
aí sempre mostra "down"