# Executar multiplos processos no Linux com Python

Tags: python

Eu recebo algumas URLs como parametro via MQTT, depois de extrai-las consigo executar o comando para o FFMPEG gravá-las com os.system. Mas isso funciona para apenas para um processo, e eu preciso executar N simultaneamente.

Venho do Java e não imagino como fazer isso em Python...

```
import paho.mqtt.client as paho
import json
import os


def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    content = str(message.payload.decode("utf-8"))
    conversor(content)


def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    client.subscribe("cameras/gravacao")


def on_disconnect():
    connect_to_mqtt()


def connect_to_mqtt():
    client = paho.Client("id")
    client.username_pw_set("", "")
    client.on_connect = on_connect
    client.on_disconnect = on_disconnect
    client.on_message = on_message
    client.connect("localhost", 1883, 60)
    client.loop_forever()


def conversor(content):
    data = json.loads(content)
    for n in range(data.get("videos")):
        os.system("ffmpeg -i " + data.get("remote_urls")[n]['url'] + "-acodec copy -vcodec copy "
                                                                     "/home/user/Vídeos/output.mp4")


connect_to_mqtt()
```

Comment: Essa pergunta te ajuda? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/290167/5878

Comment: Estudarei por ele, não entendi como passar as URLs (afinal nem sempre receberei um tamanho fixo) mas já é um começo. Obrigado :)

Comment: A maior diferença do que está na minha resposta para essa outra pergunta sugerira é que o método `call` do subprocess espera o subprocesso chamado terminar. O Popen sem outros parâmetros inicia o processo num processo paralelo do S.O. e continua a execução do código Python.
Na pegunta sugerida, o autor tenta deixar as coisas em paralelo usando "multiprocessing" e "threads" do lado do Python, mas realmente não é necessário.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você teria de fazer algo mais ou menos assim:

```
async def command(*args):
    process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(*args, stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE)
    cria_arquivo_com_pid(process.pid)
    stdout, stderr = await process.communicate()
    return stdout.decode() if process.returncode == 0 else stderr.decode()

def gravacao():
    comandos_gravacao = []
    for url in URLS:
        comandos_gravacao.append(command('ffmpeg', '-i', url, '-acodec', 'copy', '-vcodec', 'copy',
                                dirs + 'video.mp4'))

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    processes = asyncio.gather(*comandos_gravacao)
    loop.run_until_complete(processes)
    loop.close()

gravacao()
```

Isso realmente é algo mais avançado do Python.

Answer (score 5):

O `os.system` quebra um galho no ambiente interativo, ou em scripts bem pequeninhos, substituindo algum shell-script também pequeno.

Para se ter um controle melhor sobre processos usados a partir de um programa em Python, as funcionalidades estão agrupadas no módulo [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).

No caso, você nem precisa de múltiplas threads no programa em Python e nenhum outro complicador - simplesmente tem que poder disparar um subprocesso - ele roda em paralelo com o seu programa, coordenado pelo sistema operacional. Eventualmente você pode consultar o resultado do processo para saber ser se ele terminou, se deu erro - mas dependendo do grau de sofisticação que você queira, não precisa nem isso.

Em suma, para chamar um processo externo e continuar a execução do código Python, substitua sua chamada a `os.system` por:

```
import subprocess

...
    proc = subprocess.Popen(["ffmpeg", "-i", data.get("remote_urls")[n]['url'],  "-acodec", "copy", "-vcodec", "copy"])
```

Isso é - a maior diferença é quem em vez de ter a string do comando como seria digitada no terminal, cada parâmetro deve ser um elemento de uma lista, que é passada para o Popen. O retorno é um objeto do tipo Popen, que tem a documentação no link acima, e pode ser usado para consultar se o processo ainda está rodando, e, com outros parâmetros passados ao Popen, verificar a saída do mesmo para stdin, ou em stderr.

Se  a lista com as opções ficar muito estranha, nada impede que você escreva ela como uma string mesmo, e use o operador "split" para transformar numa lista:

```
executavel = 'ffmpeg'
url = data.get("remote_urls")[n]['url']
parametros = "-acodec copy -vcodec copy /home/user/Vídeos/output.mp4".split()
proc = subprocess.Popen([executavel, "-i", url] + parametros)
```

Comment: se quiser usar uma string, uma dica é usar o [`shlex.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.split) que segue as regras do shell para dividir a string, considerando coisas como aspas.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, todavia, eu precisaria executar esse comando muitas vezes. Num comentário acima, foi postado o link pra outro post que me serviu muito bem, mas levarei essa sua resposta pra vida toda!