# Multiprocessing em Python

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, raspberry-pi

Estou criando processos utilizando `multiprocessing` em Python, mas preciso criar processos dentro de outros processos, ou seja, processos filhos. É possível fazer isso utilizando `multiprocessing`?

Código:

```
import time
import multiprocessing

def calc_square():
    while 1:
        time.sleep(1)
        print("square: %i" %(3*3*3))

def calc_cube():
    while 1:
        time.sleep(1)
        print("cube: %i" %(2*2*2))
        p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=calc_square)
        p2.start()
        p2.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=calc_cube)
    p1.start()
    p1.join()
```

Ao criar o processo `calc_cube`, ele dá `print` no `cube` uma vez e cria o processo `calc_square`, e apenas mostra os `print` do `calc_square`, ou seja, os dois processos não rodam em paralelo.

É possível fazer rodarem em paralelo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não há nenhuma restrição ao uso de multiprocessing de dentro de um processo criado pelo próprio multiprocessing. Mas o seu sistema está fazendo *exatamente* o que você manda ele fazer:

De dentro do `calc_cube`, ele dorme um segundo, imprime uma vez o cubo, inicia o processo `calc_square` e **fica esperando o calc_square terminar**. Como esse outro fica num loop infinito e nunca termina, só ele vai imprimir respostas. Qual é a surpresa?

Se você reordenar as instruções dentro co calc_cube de forma a fazer sentido: criar um único processo do calc_square (e não tentar criar um novo processo a cada execução do loop), e ficar imprimindo seus resultados sem se preocupar em esperar o outro processo, vai ver as duas impressões acontecendo simultaneamente:

```
def calc_cube():
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=calc_square)
    p2.start()  # inicia uma única instância do outro processo
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print("cube: %i" %(2*2*2))

    p2.join()  # essa linha nunca será atingida - pois está fora do while. Se o código mudar para o calc_cube ter um fim, aí sim ela faz sentido.
```

Pronto - isso vai funcionar e você pode testar no PC - não precisa se dar ao trabalho de colocar no rasp.
Agora - é preciso ter em mente que você não vai ter muitas vantagens de usar estratégias desse tipo - o multiprocessing é legal se você tem CPUs com vários núcleos, e mesmo assim, até o limite de 1 processo por núcleo, para algoritmos com cálculo intenso, ou 2 processos por núcleo, "estourando". Os recursos do sistema operacional que processos usam são muito grandes  e você vai ter vantagens, principalmente numa máquina com um único núcleo, se usar asyncio  - uma única thread alternando rapidamente entre código que sempre tem algo a fazer, enquanto outras partes do código esperam respostas de E/S.

Aqui eu escrevi uma resposta onde trato extensivamente o tópico de paralelização de código em Python: [O que é Global Interpreter Lock (GIL)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/253308/o-que-%C3%A9-global-interpreter-lock-gil/253411#253411)